# pandas read_csv parse dates

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have written this date parsing function

```
def date_parser(string):
   try:
       date = pd.datetime.strptime(string, "%d/%m/%Y")
   except:
       date = pd.NaT
   return date
```

and I call it in pd.read_csv like this

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file),
                 sep=";",
                 encoding="latin-1",
                 keep_default_na=False,
                 na_values=na_values,
                 index_col=False,
                 usecols=keep,
                 dtype=dtype,
                 date_parser=date_parser,
                 parse_dates=dates)
```

The problem is that in one of my dates column, I end up with mixed data types

```
df[data].apply(type).value_counts()
```

- class 'datetime.datetime'
- class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'
- class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType'

I should only have the last two right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest change your function by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for return `NaT` if not matched format `%d/%m/%Y`:

```
def date_parser(string):
   return pd.to_datetime(string, format="%d/%m/%Y", errors='coerce')
```